# How to deal with really large terms generated by Program Fixpoint in Coq?

Tags: coq

I'm attempting to define and prove correct in Coq a function that efficiently diffs two sorted lists. As it does not always recurse on a structurally smaller term (either the first or second list is smaller), `Fixpoint` won't accept it, so I'm attempting to use `Program Fixpoint` instead.

When attempting to prove a property of the function using the tactic `simpl` or `program_simpl`, Coq spends minutes computing and then produces a giant term, hundreds of lines long. I was wondering if I'm using `Program Fixpoint` the wrong way, or alternatively if there are other tactics that should be used instead of simplification when reasoning about it?

I also wondered if it's good practice to include the required properties for correctness in params like this, or would it be better to have a separate wrapper function that takes the correctness properties as params, and make this function just take the two lists to be diffed?

Note that I  did try defining a simpler version of `make_diff`, which only took l1 and l2 as parameters and fixed the type `A` and relation `R`, but this still produced a gigantic term when the `program_simpl` or `simpl` tactics were applied.

*Edit: my includes are (although they may not all be required here):

```
Require Import Coq.Sorting.Sorted.
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Require Import Coq.Relations.Relation_Definitions.
Require Import Recdef.
Require Import Coq.Program.Wf.
Require Import Coq.Program.Tactics.
```

The code:

```
Definition is_decidable (A : Type) (R : relation A) := forall x y, {R x y} + {~(R x y)}.
Definition eq_decidable (A : Type) := forall (x y : A), { x = y } + { ~ (x = y) }.

Inductive diff (X: Type) : Type :=
  | add : X -> diff X
  | remove : X -> diff X 
  | update : X -> X -> diff X.

Program Fixpoint make_diff (A : Type) 
    (R : relation A)
    (dec : is_decidable A R)
    (eq_dec : eq_decidable A)
    (trans : transitive A R) 
    (lt_neq : (forall x y, R x y -> x <> y))
    (l1 l2 : list A)
     {measure (length l1 + length l2) } : list (diff A) :=
  match l1, l2 with
  | nil, nil => nil
  | nil, (new_h::new_t) => (add A new_h) :: (make_diff A R dec eq_dec trans lt_neq nil new_t)
  | (old_h::old_t), nil => (remove A old_h) :: (make_diff A R dec eq_dec trans lt_neq old_t nil)
  | (old_h::old_t) as old_l, (new_h::new_t) as new_l => 
    if dec old_h new_h 
      then (remove A old_h) :: make_diff A R dec eq_dec trans lt_neq old_t new_l
      else if eq_dec old_h new_h 
        then (update A old_h new_h) :: make_diff A R dec  eq_dec trans lt_neq old_t new_t
        else  (add A new_h) :: make_diff A R dec eq_dec trans lt_neq old_l new_t 
  end.
Next Obligation.
Proof.
  simpl.
  generalize dependent (length new_t).
  generalize dependent (length old_t).
  auto with arith.
Defined.
Next Obligation.
Proof.
  simpl.
  generalize dependent (length new_t).
  generalize dependent (length old_t).
  auto with arith.
Defined.
```

Comment: A couple of observations: **(1)** I think you *can* implement it with only `Fixpoint` (I tried to show how to do it [here](https://gist.github.com/anton-trunov/2b2495560857f48d12ab083b1913aabf). **(2)** If you get rid of the unused parameters (`trans` and `lt_neq`) `Program Fixpoint` works way faster.

Comment: @AntonTrunov Thanks, I didn't realise it could be done that way. If you add it as an answer, I'll accept it, and it might live longer than in a Gist.

Comment: All right, done! I've slightly brushed the code.

Comment: Please also add the libraries you include. It is a pain to figure out which ones you included.

Comment: Based on Anton's comment and answer, you can try to remove from the recursion all the arguments that are the same at all the recursive calls. Here, only `l1` and `l2` vary. All the other arguments can be removed from the recursive function. You can then put them in a wrapper function or using the Section mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case we can get rid of `Program Fixpoint` and use plain simple `Fixpoint`. Since at each recursive call we invoke `make_diff` either on the tail of the first list or on the tail of the second list, we can nest two fixed-point functions as follows. (I have used the `Section` mechanism here to avoid passing too many identical arguments)

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.
Require Import Coq.Relations.Relations.

Section Make_diff.

Variable A : Type.
Variable R : relation A.
Variable dec : is_decidable A R.
Variable eq_dec : eq_decidable A.
Variable trans : transitive A R.
Variable lt_neq : forall x y, R x y -> x <> y.

Fixpoint make_diff (l1 l2 : list A) : list (diff A) :=
  let fix make_diff2 l2 :=
  match l1, l2 with
  | nil, nil => nil
  | nil, new_h::new_t => (add A new_h) :: make_diff2 new_t
  | old_h::old_t, nil => (remove A old_h) :: make_diff old_t nil
  | old_h::old_t, new_h::new_t =>
    if dec old_h new_h 
    then (remove A old_h) :: make_diff old_t l2
    else if eq_dec old_h new_h 
         then (update A old_h new_h) :: make_diff old_t new_t
         else (add A new_h) :: make_diff2 new_t
  end
  in make_diff2 l2.

End Make_diff.
```

Observe that the `Section` mechanism won't include unused parameters in the resulting signature. Here is a naive test:

```
(* make the first 2 arguments implicit *)    
Arguments make_diff [A R] _ _ _ _.

Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.

Compute make_diff lt_dec Nat.eq_dec [1;2;3] [4;5;6].
(* = [remove nat 1; remove nat 2; remove nat 3; add nat 4; add nat 5; add nat 6] 
      : list (diff nat) *)
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who comes across the, a better alternative now is the [Equations](https://github.com/mattam82/Coq-Equations) plugin, which will eventually replace Function and Program Fixpoint.

Comment: But does this answer the question? Does the plugin generate smaller terms?

Comment: @AntonTrunov The plugin generates small rewrite rules, which can be used for reasoning instead of simpl / program_simpl.

Comment: +1 It would also be great if you added your comment into your answer (and possibly a code sample for `make_diff`).