# Why doesn't Coq's termination checker support the case where one argument gets structurally smaller and others remain the same

Tags: coq, termination

Coq's termination checker does not like functions like:

```
Fixpoint interleave (A : Type) (l1 l2 : list A) : list A :=
  match l1 with 
  | cons h1 t1 => cons h1 (interleave l2 t1)
  | nil => l2
  end.
```

<s>Some other languages with similar termination checkers, however, such as Lean, Idris and Isabelle, accept such functions</s>. I'm wondering why Coq's termination checker will not accept such functions, where at least one argument gets structurally smaller each time, and no arguments get bigger. It seems to me that if at least one argument is always getting smaller and none are growing, the function must eventually terminate, or is there some case I'm missing?

*Edit: Seems I've picked a terrible example here as apparently Idris and Lean cannot handle it either. A better example would be the fix-in-fix formulation given in [How to deal with really large terms generated by Program Fixpoint in Coq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44612214/how-to-deal-with-really-large-terms-generated-by-program-fixpoint-in-coq/44630688#44630688); I know I managed to implement that same function in Lean and Idris directly without requiring the fix-in-fix construction. Also, the original question still stands: why isn't that construction supported?*

Comment: Indeed Coq termination checker is one generation older than the one used in the languages you mention, so it is not so powerful. You can use the `Equations` plugin to get something much closer to state of the art termination checking in Coq.

Comment: @ejgallego Apparently sometimes even "modern" dependently-typed languages cannot beat good old Coq :) See e.g. [this Idris issue](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/issues/3661#issuecomment-284241741)

Comment: Idris does not accept this function as total (I tried with Idris v1.1.1)

Comment: Lean (version 3.3.1, commit 1b4d2a850afd) does not accept it either

Comment: @AntonTrunov Sorry, seems I picked a bad example; I've updated the question. I still wonder though is there anything in particular that prevents that construct from being supported?

Comment: @ejgallego The Equations looks extremely useful, I'm surprised I've never heard of it before. Is it something that might eventually replace / be integrated into Function or Program Fixpoint when they are are unified, or is it unlikely ever to be integrated into the main Coq distribution?

Comment: `Equations` indeed is the successor of `Function` and `Program` and it is already officially supported by the Coq dev team. And indeed, at some point it will be distributed with Coq.

Comment: If all else fails, you could manually define the appropriate "smaller than" relation on pairs of arguments, prove it's well-founded (and possibly make sure that proof is a transparent definition if you need to evaluate the function), then write a helper function which takes an `Acc` proof as an extra argument to set as the decreasing argument of the fixpoint.

Comment: or simply use a `measure` which is the sum of the `length`s of the two lists.

Answer (score 1):

Like gallais suggests, you can use `measure`:

```
Require Import PeanoNat.
Require Import Coq.Program.Wf.

Program Fixpoint interleave (A : Type) (l1 l2 : list A) {measure (length l1 + length l2)} : list A :=
  match l1 with
  | nil => l2
  | cons h1 t1 => cons h1 (interleave A l2 t1)
  end.
Next Obligation.
  simpl.
  rewrite Nat.add_comm.
  apply Nat.lt_succ_diag_r.
Defined.
Next Obligation.
Admitted.
```

After the definition you need to prove two things: first, that at each step the measure decreases; and second, that the measure is well founded. After completing the two proofs, your definition is done.